# How to pass Design attributes values from Lightning Page to Related list button in Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, related-list

I have a custom LWC which contains some design attributes defined in meta.XML file.
I need to create a Related list button which will contain an Aura component.

I want to pass the value(s) of these design attributes to the Related list button without using LWC on the Lightning Page.

Is it possible ?
If not Is there any other way to achieve it ?

Please help me on this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community Edited the question .. Please check and help me on this.